# How can I save my JSON response from my online database to my local database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json

I have a button click event

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameValueCollection userInfo = new NameValueCollection();
        userInfo.Add("cardno", textBox6.Text);
        byte[] getCart = client.UploadValues("http://eallowance.x10host.com/v1/getCart.php", "POST", userInfo);
    }
```

that will call my getCart.php

```
<?php 

$cardno = $_POST['cardno'];

include_once('../includes/constants.php');

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM costing WHERE cardno = $cardno;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);$response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($response,array('cardno'=>$row[1],'product_id'=>$row[2], 'name'=>$row[3], 'quantity'=>$row[4], 'price'=>$row[5], 'category'=>$row[6]));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    echo json_encode(array('cart'=>$response));
```

and will echo an array in JSON format:

```
{"cart":[{"cardno":"3333333333","product_id":"10000104","name":"Hotsilog","quantity":"1","price":"35","category":"breakfast"},{"cardno":"3333333333","product_id":"10000131","name":"Fudgee bar choco","quantity":"1","price":"7","category":"snacks"}]}
```

that has a column of product_id, name, quantity, price, and category.

Im using a free hosting site that doesnt allow remote access to the database because its free, so I have to use php, im using my php in my android application writen in Java. Im new to c# and dont know what to call my problem.

How can i save the JSON array response to my local database with the same column.

Comment: By using Newtonsoft.Json library you can deserialize that JSON into an object and then use Entity Framework to save it to your database.